# Order By clause in sql server

Tags: sql

Suppose, there is a table and I need to sort one of its column (name) alphabetically and at the same time I want to sort it by using ID column  in asc order based on the condition ( rows that have same name). So, I failed to understand how this will work. Once the records will be sorted by column (name) then will it sort all rows by using id column?
Can someone explain how actually order by clause works in this case

```
   select name, 
          id  
     from hack h 
 order by name,
          id
```

Comment: Sort by `substring(name, len(name) - 2, len(name))`, in case of **tie** (several records have the *same value* for `substring(name, len(name) - 2, len(name))`), use `id`

Comment: the query you've written is correct if you want to first sort by **name** and then by **ID** column.

Comment: My bad. I just realized that I had written some another code. I corrected the code now :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand? What do you mean by "how this will work"?

Comment: @user11497433 . . . You have pretty much described how the code works, so I fail to understand what needs to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

use `order by name, id`

```
   select name, 
          id  
     from hack 
 order by name,
          id
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to understand what you want to know, you want to realize how it happens when the order by clause have two or more columns ,am I right? Let's go to an example,

```
the first column is id and the second is name,
2 A
5 B
6 A
3 A
1 B

the result of SQL "select name,id from hack order by name,id" will get the result as below
A 2
A 3
A 6
B 1
B 5

see, it will sort first by name column, and then sort id in the same name value group.
```

That's it ,did I make it clear?

Comment: Yes. Got your point that second column will sort id in same name value group. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome, please click the accepted button for me ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This answers the **original** question.
In the code you posted:

```
substring(name, len(name) - 2, len(name))
```

returns the last 3 characters of the `name`. 
So you are sorting by these last 3 characters and **not** by `name`.
When there are 2 names with the same last 3 characters these will be sorted by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one column names after "order by" keyword, the system orders the records according to the first column just after order by.